# Getting access to class declared in a file applied with 'apply from' in gradle

Tags: gradle

Hi I want to create a class in a separate file from my main `build.gradle`, when I run gradle I get `... Build file: build.gradle line: 2 ... > Could not get Property 'Foo' for root project ...`

My files:

```
// build.gradle
apply from: 'foo.gradle'
println Foo // <- Line 2


// foo.gradle
class Foo {
}
```

Comment: I found that I can add `ext.Foo = Foo` but is this the best solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation:

> You can include the task class directly in the build script. This has the benefit that the task class is automatically compiled and included in the classpath of the build script without you having to do anything. **However, the task class is not visible outside the build script, and so you cannot reuse the task class outside the build script it is defined in.**

<sup>[Source](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html?_ga=2.261802059.718782579.1496855474-1334641024.1485988099#sec:packaging_a_task_class)</sup>

You have 2 options to work around that

1. like you've found out you can use `ext.Foo = Foo` inside the `foo.gradle`
2. use the `buildSrc` feature from gradle [have a look at this for more information](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:build_sources)